# Remove a field from json in wp rest api v1

Tags: json, wp-api

I want to create an android app for a WordPress blog using WordPress rest api.

For optimization I want to remove content field and some other fields when I get all post to show them in my main list and when user click on a link fetch the content filed from the post link.

Is there any way to remove them?

Comment: I think you could use [WP-REST-API-Filter-Items](https://github.com/bueltge/WP-REST-API-Filter-Items) plugin. With the plugin you can define a list of fields you want and you do not have to fiddle with WordPress or PHP.

Comment: PS! We re not here to teach you. We expect that you know the basics. :-)

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks for mentioning that. I keep it in my mind.@PieterGoosen

Comment: Wow, Exactly what i want, it is super, even in my little data test my file shrink from 152 to 27 KB, So it can be so effective in real data. can u add an answer so i submit your post as answer? @ville6000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use [WP-REST-API-Filter-Items plugin](https://github.com/bueltge/WP-REST-API-Filter-Items). With the plugin you can define a list of fields you want and you do not have to fiddle with WordPress or PHP